# QML onMyPropertyChanged is it "on set" or "on set to different value"

Tags: qt, qml

QML automatically creates signals for properties.

With QML does the property signal for `onMyPropertyChanged` get fired when the property is set to same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, the signal will be emitted when the property value actually changes.

The behavior is consistent with the "standard" for implementing property setters in C++, if new value is different set and emit notification, else do nothing.

Also it may be worth mentioning that notification will not be emitted for internal changes, for example if the property is a JS object and it has some of its properties changed. In this case you can force reevaluation by emitting the appropriate signal manually.